# WPF combobox highlight

Tags: wpf, combobox, text-search

In WPF, when I enter some text in combobox, it will highlight the item starting with the text I entered. This highlighting will search the whole text i have entered in the combo box. But instead i want the text search to match only the first letter. How to do this?

Actually, I want to make TextSearch.Text to be always first character.

Answer (score 1):

Ive done something similar to this. Found a sort of howto on a blog post, dont have the link saved but did a new search now and found [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx), which (from my memory) looks quite similar.